# How can i stop a music file using soundeffect class for windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

Hi I am making a windows phone app. I used some sound tracks using  [Soundeffect class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffect.aspx) but I want to stop the music of that track on a button clicking event (it has a play method but does not have a stop method) so how can I achieve this ? The language used is C#

Comment: Can you post some sample code, showing what you have in place so far, or have tried and not succeeded with?

Answer (score 3):

The `Play` method provided by `SoundEffect` is just a convenience method for doing fire-and-forget sounds. You need to create a `SoundEffectInstance` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd282421)) if you want to do anything more fancy.

```
// At load time:
SoundEffect mySoundEffect = Content.Load<SoundEffect>("mySound");
SoundEffectInstance mySoundEffectInstance = mySoundEffect.CreateInstance();

// During your game:
mySoundEffectInstance.Play();
mySoundEffectInstance.Stop();

// When you're done with it:
mySoundEffectInstance.Dispose();
```

(Note that you do not `Dispose()` of `mySoundEffect`, as its lifetime is managed by the `ContentManager` that loaded it.)

Answer (score 0):

I think the Soundeffect class should be used for short sound effects you would not want to pause because they are short.

Are you using XNA ? If yes, have a look at [the MediaPlayer class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.mediaplayer.aspx).
If not, try using [the BackgroundAudioPlayer class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.backgroundaudio.backgroundaudioplayer%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).